# Why can I not use filter_input to get information from a form where $_get works just fine

Tags: php, html, arrays, filter, get

I am using get method with a form in order to store information of checkboxes status into an array

I have attempted to use a filter_input line to take information from each checkbox sequentially and store it into an array, everything works just fine when replaced with $_get instead, but I have been told not to use $_get for the sake of security.

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="checkbox" name="1">Show Name<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="2">Show Category<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="3">Show Type<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
$formArray = array();
$x = 1;
while ($x < 4) {
    if (isset($_GET[$x]))  {    
        $formArray[$x] = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "$x", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH)  
    }
    else {
        $formArray[$x] = "off";
    }
    $x = $x + 1;
}
?>
```

The array should then store the values of "on" or "off" but it is just left blank, as I have mentioned when replaced with "`$formArray[$x] = $_GET["$x"];`", The program functions 100% correctly

Comment: The argument to `isset()` has to be a variable. Just use `if(filter_input(...))`

Comment: Thank you for creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing filter_input,

core implementation of filter_input is as follows,

```
$b = isset($_GET['b']) && is_string($_GET['b']) ? $_GET['b'] : '';
```

Name of your element is an integer. So filter_input will return false  if name is not string and null if name is not set.

I have modified your snippet to make it work,

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="checkbox" name="t1">Show Name<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="t2">Show Category<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="t3">Show Type<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_GET)) {
        $formArray = [];
        $x         = 1;
        while ($x < 4) {
            if (isset($_GET['t' . $x])) {
                $formArray[$x] = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 't' . $x, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
            } else {
                $formArray[$x] = "off";
            }
            $x = $x + 1;
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($formArray);
        die;
}
?>
```

If 2 is checked,
**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [1] => off
    [2] => on
    [3] => off
)
```

And the filter flags you are using are for the data element is carrying.

By [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).

Comment: This looks like a bug in `filter_input` to me, why does it returns NULL if the variable name is a number ???

Comment: Rasmus may answer that question :D.

Comment: Who is Rasmus ?

Comment: [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) [Designed by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design) [Rasmus Lerdorf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasmus_Lerdorf)